# Evaluated by using vs Evaluated by

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference between following sentences:

> 1. XXX has been evaluated by Y1,Y2 and Y3?
> 2. XXX has been evaluated by using Y1,Y2 and Y3?
> 3. XXX has been evaluated using Y1,Y2 and Y3

I cannot decide if adding a **"using"** here makes meaning clear or it is redundant for this type of sentence. I added third one as @FumbleFingers suggested. I would like to learn "is there a subtle difference between these usages?".

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are Y1, Y2, and Y3 tools, criteria, people, or something else?

Comment: You missed out **XXX has been evaluated using Y1,Y2 and Y3**. They're all perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 'evaluated by' when Y1, Y2, and Y3 are the people or organizations doing the evaluation.

You should use 'evaluated by using' when Y1, Y2, and Y2 are the methods used for evaluation.

Comment: I can't agree with that distinction. There's nothing wrong with saying *"Our company's performance has been evaluated using an external assessment team"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In that case, the method used was "an external assessment team." Most things that satisfy the requirements for "by" will also satisfy the requirements for "by using".

Comment: @MrHen: That's true. But by [using] that principle, do you endorse Igor's distinction or not? I think it's totally spurious, and that **by** and **using** are effectively synonyms in such contexts - in many case you can use *either or both*, as the mood takes you.

Comment: I think it is a minor, but accurate, distinction. Personally, I wouldn't say "by using" and would just use "using". This matters ever so slightly more when Y1, Y2 and Y3 are actually mathematical methods but, for the most part, I wouldn't complain if someone only ever used "by".